# What is the "store" process?

Tags: top, ubuntu-store

Looking through top, I saw a process called "store" taking up one of my CPUs. What is this process? Perhaps it is referring to the app store? If so, I wonder why it is working in the background.

Googling was unhelpful because "store" is too commonly used with other meanings. man, info, and help all did not have an entry for "store."

Comment: Try pressing `c` to see the process in detail. Also, try the command `ps -fp <pid>`, using the PID seen in `top`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the process is not visible in top any more. I will see if I can figure out how to search for a process called "store."

Comment: "ps aux | grep store" yields "zach     22253  0.0  0.0  16504  1052 pts/4    S+   09:14   0:00 grep --color=auto store" if that helps

Comment: no, that's just the `grep` in `ps aux | grep`.

Comment: Ok then finding more details from ps may not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Linux PC) process "store" was running by steam client.